# how to search list view item through Edit text in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

hello I have issue about searching text of list item in Edit text when I am writing some alphabet in Edit text there given me many combination of text so how to get only matching starting text my app image add here check it and[image] help me

my code is

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) 
            {
                property p = new property (state[i],
                        website[i]);

                arraylist.add(p);
            }


            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);


            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            editsearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);


            editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                    adapter.filter(text);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/android-listview-search-using-filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you function `onTextChanged` to:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count) {

    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
}
```

Comment: why??!!
refer to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: I already refer this website and one thing I have use array adapter to set text view in list view but when I am type some text it gives error unfortunately close and LogCat show null pointer exaption

Comment: Go to Manage apps >> Select “All” tab >> Select your app (or process) that has the error >> Clear cache and data. Rerun the app. If it doesn’t work try steps below.